# All the possible ways to export/import categories with ids

Tags: magento-1.9, category, importexport, category-tree

I am transferring my store to a fresh installation and I need to know, what are the possible ways to export all my existing categories with their respective Ids, description, title etc and import it to my new installation. I have tried 1 or 2 extension but they doesn't seem to work properly. My current store is running on ver 1.7.02 and I am transferring it to ver 1.9.2.4

Need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep you 1.7.0.2 information you can do in a simple way:

1. Dump you database from 1.7.0.2
2. Import your dump to the new database
3. Point the 1.9.2.4 installation to the new database by editing `app/etc/local.xml`. No need to run the setup procedure

I did it a lot of times without problems. When your 1.9.2.4 Magento will check your DB it will upgrade to the new Magento version and you will keep all your information. You catalog will be copied as well as your customers and so on.

Just make sure you have the same payment method modules as well as the shipping methods if you want to see old orders. If you do not want old customers or old orders to be copied you can clean them after your new install.

**NOTE: This may leave some orphan information if your Magento 1.9.2.4 installation has different modules operating on DB, but nothing to concern, it should work without problems.**

Comment: Hey RiccardoT, will it also bring back the errors, that I am having in my current store because the main reason that I am shifting is because I installed an extension in my store and it messed up the catalog in admin area. I mean whenever I try to add a new product on ver 1.7.02, I get an error. I can do everything but can't add or edit any product

Comment: It depends on the error. What is the error? Can you paste it?

Comment: When I try to add a product, first I get "There has been an error processing your request" and in var/report I get this,  [link](http://i.imgur.com/SjGoINt.jpg) I have already deleted this extension cartmart but the error still persist.

Comment: I am scared to transfer the whole database cause I think I have messed up my database with some stupid extensions.

Comment: This is because you probably disabled/installed a module named "cartmart" without removing the custom attribute it added to your products. If this is your case you can solve by running this SQL query: "delete from eav_attribute where source_model='cartmart/product_attribute_source_vendor';" This will fix your 1.7.0.2 and will avoid to carry the error with your db. If you are not 100% sure of what you are doing make a DB copy before running this.

Comment: Do I have to solve this issue before importing? If I import the database without making any changes, will it bring back this error to the fresh installation?

Comment: You can do this both before or after. Because you will transport this error with your dump

Comment: You are welcome ;)